# Prepending a string to alternate elements in a Python tuple

Tags: python

So I have this piece of Python code that essentially takes a tuple, then modifies the second (and every other) element by prepending a string to it.  Unfortunately the only way I can think to do it is convert it to a list (as tuples are immutable), step through, edit and then convert back to a tuple.

It works so I can't put it on SO but it's ugly and I'm sure there's a more Pythonic way to do this using slices or something.

```
def prependPackageToEnpoints(urls, packageName):
    """Take web.py formatted url/endpoint tuples and prepend 
    a packageName to each of the endpoints, e.g.
    ('/Test/(.*)', 'test') becomes ('/Test/(.*)', 'Test.test')"""
    lst = list(urls)
    for i in xrange(1, len(lst), 2):
        lst[i] = packageName + "." + lst[i]
    t = tuple(lst)

    return t
```

I don't get to decide what the structure is, I'm using [web.py](http://webpy.org/) and the structure it uses is a tuple.

What's the prettiest, and perhaps the most efficient way to do something like this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a nicer way to do it that's prettier, more concise and seems more Pythonic/Pythony.  Still technically converting it to a list and back but using slices to loop over both subsets at the same time:-

```
def prependPackageToEnpoints(urls, packageName):
    newList = []
    for url, endpoint in zip(urls[::2], urls[1::2]):
        newList += [url, "{}.{}".format(packageName, endpoint)]
    return tuple(newList)
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be other ways to do it, but none that I can think of that stands out as being better than what you wrote.  You could tighten up the code by adhering to [PEP 8 naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (use `lower_case_with_underscores`) and eliminating the variable `t`.

All I can offer is my condolences for being stuck with this stupid interface.  Note that the first thing that webpy does, as you might expect, is [split up the tuple into pairs](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/webpy-0.37/web/application.py#L115), using [their own `utils.group()` function](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/webpy-0.37/web/utils.py#L536).

> ```
> class application:
>     def __init__(self, mapping=(), fvars={}, autoreload=None):
>         if autoreload is None:
>             autoreload = web.config.get('debug', False)
>         self.init_mapping(mapping)
>         …
>
>  def init_mapping(self, mapping):
>     self.mapping = list(utils.group(mapping, 2))
> ```

Comment: At least `utils.group` does not specifically expect a tuple, so there is no added value converting `lst` back to a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you abuse the slice notation even more and modify the list in place:

```
def prependPackageToEnpoints(urls, packageName):
    l_urls = list(urls)
    l_urls[1::2] = [packageName + "." + x for x in urls[1::2]]
    return tuple(l_urls)
```

Comment: Now that's what I'm talking about, moar Pythonic!

Comment: it would be even nicer if urls was already a list :)